# openlayers - WMS do not load completly

Tags: javascript, render, openlayers, tiles, wms

I have one problematic WMS layer. The layer loads but not every single tile. When change zoom map is reloaded but few tiles are white. Is there a parameter which should I use for?

the WMS layer:

```
const wmsAddressGeoportalOrthoHighRes = "https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WMS/HighResolution"

const wmsSource_orto = new TileWMS({
    url: wmsAddressGeoportalOrthoHighRes,
    params: {
        LAYERS: wmsSourceOrtoLayer,
    },
    serverType: "geoserver",
})
```

The efect is shown below:
[printscreen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2ISf.jpg)
[printscreen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtp7Z.jpg)

----- edit -----
I have changed wms to wmts and effect is still occure.

The wmts configuration you can find in sandbox:
[codesanbox WMTS](https://codesandbox.io/s/wmts-layer-from-capabilities-forked-6gu26y?file=/main.js)
The problem in sandbox is not so common but it shows up. When I use the same code in my application I have problem almost all the time.
Where to look for the problem? How to solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT6qZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem was in coordinate system. The WMTS layer is in EPSG2180 but map was in default EPSG3857. When I change map coordinate system (using proj4) to EPSG2180 the problem was solved.